# Get Data URL from Canvas with SVG (on the same domain) Causes Security Error

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, svg, chromium

In some tests of my JavaScript application, I want to check if the canvas is correctly drawn. Some SVG images, which comes from the same domain as the script, are drawn on the canvas.

To do so, I compare the result of the `toDataURL()` method of the canvas with the same result of the expected image.

While this works fine in Firefox, this causes a security error in Chromium (`Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18`) and Internet Explorer (`SCRIPT5022: SecurityError`).

Is there a way to bypass this restriction with a HTTP header, a browser option or anything else?

As it will be only use to test an application, I don't care if it removes some security from the browser.

I would at least like be able to do this in IE since I had to use some hacks to make the application works, but I'll be glad to be able to execute these tests in Chrome too.

Comment: If you only want to test an application just use Firefox to do so. The other browsers will catch up someday!

Comment: Like I said, there is some code that is only executed in IE. It is why I want at least, to execute the tests in IE.

Comment: Not much chance with IE but for Chrome you could write a patch for http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249037 or pay someone to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Append the following flag to bypass the same-origin-policy in Chromium:

- chrome.exe `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Use a shortcut or command line alias to switch between the two modes.

For IE, add both sites to the Trusted Sites zone:

- [Adding or Removing websites](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/security-zones-adding-or-removing-websites)